# How to count SYN/ESTABLISHED connection to server?

Tags: c++, c, netstat

I want to get number of SYN and ESTABLISHED connection to my server with C/C++. But I don't want to call popen to run netstat, or any other Linux command. I've managed to scan /proc/net/ip_conntrack and get the numbers. But I realize that scanning ip_conntrack requires great resources, each time my application invoke that method. Is there any other simple way?

Comment: CPU Usage. Scanning /proc/net/ip_conntrack use 99% of CPU Resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanning `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` is not reliable because it only works if netfilter/connection tracking is enabled. And it doesn't only count connections **to** your server but also **through** your server (if it's acting as a router).

Better would be to get the information in the same places as `netstat` does: `/proc/net/tcp`, `/proc/net/tcp6` (and similar files for UDP and other protocols if you care about those). That amount more or less to reimplementing `netstat` inside your application though. You have to wonder if it's worth it. Also, it's portable (more or less) to call `netstat` whereas reading those files directly is Linux-specific.

I know you are concerned about the resources requires to scan the full table every time, but I don't think there's a say to "subscribe" and get notifications when new connections are established or torn down. The closest thing I can think of to something like that would be to sniff the network interface (using libpcap) and keeping track of connection setups and teardowns yourself.

Comment: OK, thank you for your info. Further, I've read the manual of netstat and saw that netstat reads /proc/net/snmp. When I count established connection with netstat and compare it with /proc/net/snmp, it appears that number of TCP Current Est. connections almost the same. I think I can scan the /proc/net/snmp. So, any suggestion for scanning SYN_RECV connections?

Comment: Good catch on finding that the `snmp` file already contains the total. For SYN_RECV connections it looks like you have to scan `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/tcp6`, I don't see a total counter anywhere. There's `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog` that contains the maximum allowed, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: Yeah, finally I got the way to count it from /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/tcp6. They describe records of tcp connections, including the tcp connection state in hex. And after I compare with what I got from netstat, the statistics are most likely produce same results. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: After doing development in several days, I realize that reading /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/tcp6, which have ~1000-2000 lines, requires 5-7% of CPU usage. I try to make monitoring agent, so I hope that this tiny application won't take much CPU usage like that. Any suggestion how to optimize reading and scanning those files? Currently I use fgets and sscanf combination. Thank you.

Comment: No special suggestion, sorry. You might incrementally improve on `fgets` and `sscanf` by writing some more complicated code that maybe slurps in the whole file at once, and then again, maybe not, but anything you do will still be **O(n)**.

Comment: It's okay. I'm thinking about using `mmap`, how about that? Do you have any idea?

Comment: A more efficient solution could be had by adding code to the kernel, but short of that, `mmap` is in fact what I had in mind as an as-good-as-it-gets solution. But it's still **O(n)**, and since you're just doing a linear scan, it's not even certain that it would be any faster anyway. Benchmark it!